# Is node:nid missing?

Tags: views, 8

I installed Drupal 8.1.0 and created a view, but I don't have the option of choosing the node ID (as a contextual filter, for example) but I can select the content ID. If it isn't the same thing, why would the node ID be missing as an option?

Comment: Yeah it's the same thing :)

Comment: Thank you! phew that would have been a hard one to debug...

Answer (score 1):

Content Id is the node id in Contextual filters for Drupal 8 views.

Comment: I dont see a Content ID either.

Comment: Try searching for just "ID"?